# chown: -R: A file or directory in the path does not exist

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I am setting up passwordless authentication on one of my systems.

It works for one of the system but does not work for this specific

So how I am doing it:

puttygen generating public + private key

1. `mkdir ~/.ssh`
2. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
3. `vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. pasting the public key from puttygen
5. `chown username:groupname ~/.ssh -R`

Here it returns that file or directory does not exist, however it exists, I did pwd and tried with absolute path still same message that the path does not exist, any idea why?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Are you running this all as the target user? If so, you neither need the `~/` prefix nor the final `chown`. If not, and you're running as root, you need to replace the `~/` with an actual appropriate path to the target user's home directory. As a simplification for the `vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` consider `cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, pasting, and then Ctrl/D to exit cleanly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path that `chown` is complaining about is `-R` (judging from the title of the question).

Usually, options should come *before* other operands on the command line:

```
chown -R username:groupname ~/.ssh
```

GNU tools have the dubious habit of *rearranging* the command line so that options that are specified out of order are interpreted as if they had been specified before other operands.

The `chown` command that you are using does not seem to be a GNU variant of the command (or at least not one that implements this particular GNU behavior, which is found in other versions of `chown`, on Ubuntu for example), which means you need to do it correctly by yourself.

Apart from that, you may want to be using `~username` instead of just plain `~`, especially if you're running those commands as the root user (`~` would refer to root's home directory, not to the home directory of `username`).

Comment: thanks it resolved the issue, you are right -R at the end does not work here ...

Comment: Well spotted. I hadn't seen that the error message had been put into the title - i only looked at the question body

Comment: @roaima Yeah, it's not even the verbatim message, but enough to trigger my pattern matching circuits. And I guessed right it seems.